# I'm using for PDFMerger.But im getting this error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using for `PDFMerger`. But I'm getting this error.

> FPDF error: This document (/var/www/html/foldername/sites/files/uploads//2019030102.pdf) probably uses a compression technique which is not supported by the free parser shipped with FPDI.

Comment: By default FPDI can "only" handle PDF documents up to PDF version 1.4. Beginning with PDF version 1.5 there were new compression features introduced which involve internal structure changes how a PDF document can be created. https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/error-document-compression-technique-not-supported/